# Flutter - permission problem causing crash

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm using contacts_service package in my flutter app (https://pub.dev/packages/contacts_service).
I want to run this app  on Android and IOS as well so I added this to my Info.plist file.

```
<key>NSContactsUsageDescription</key>  
<string>This app requires contacts access to function properly.</string>
```

I'm developing this app on my android device so I've also added permissions to  AndroidManifest.xml.I've done it above <aplication </> section.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
```

But aplication crashes during execution this line of code.

```
contacts = await ContactsService.getContacts();
```

The error says :

> caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening
> provider com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 from
> ProcessRecord{f7cf96e 11239:com.example.smsresponder/u0a189}
> (pid=11239, uid=10189) requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS or
> android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS

In addition I've noticed that Android doesn't ask me for permission for this app when I'm installing it. So I'm assuming that I did something wrong with granting permissions but I have no idea what. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still need to ask user for permission in order for the app to access device contacts. It's not enough with declaring that your app will use those permissions.

Android >= 6 and iOS requires your app to ask for sensitive permissions on runtime.

> **Note** contacts_service does not handle the process of asking and
> checking for permissions. To check and request user permission to
> access contacts, try using the following plugins:
> flutter_simple_permissions or permission_handler.

Comment: Thank You very much. I was confused because I'm using package responsible for sending sms and it asking for permission automaticly

Answer (score 2):

go to build.gradle
and set targetSdkVersion  to 22

```
targetSdkVersion 22
```

and you will be fine